# Python and importing

Tags: python, nltk

I installed python 3.4.3 and NLTK-3.0.4. When I import nltk in python, the below error appeared :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named 'nltk'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you install nltk? pip?

Comment: What @Brobin means is pip install -U nltk http://www.nltk.org/install.html

Comment: I tested with the same versions on my macbook. No errors.

Comment: What platform are you on? I would suggest that it hasn't installed to a directory in python's include path...

Answer (score 0):

I just extract `nltk.rar` and then copy the folder to the below folder:

`C/python34/lib`

Note: before copying the folder, you should rename the name of the folder and just remove the numbers.

Before copying = `nltk 3.4.3`

After renaming = `nltk`

Comment: Did this work for you, or are you providing more information for your question?

Comment: Yes. It did. I import nltk in shell and then  I wrote the below commansds:

Comment: Import nltk.       nltk.download ()    after downloading the book l wrote   from nltk.book import *    then all the texts were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the instructions from the nltk website.So what's the os you are using
Mac/Unix

Install NLTK: run sudo pip install -U nltk
Install Numpy (optional): run sudo pip install -U numpy
Test installation: run python then type import nltk
For older versions of Python it might be necessary to install setuptools (see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and to install pip (sudo easy_install pip).

Windows

These instructions assume that you do not already have Python installed on your machine.

Install python 3.4 first
Install NLTK: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk
Test installation: Start>Python34, then type import nltk